# Using NIBs in UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, nib

For an ipad application in ioS5.0 using arc and storyboard, i wanted to create another custom view and instantiate several instances of that view within a scrollview so as to show a scrollable train of these custom views. To do this, I created the custom view in XIB file, however, how should I instantiate this view in the ViewController being refrenced within the storyboard. The custom view also has a gesture recogniser within it.

thank you in advance for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to instantiate a nib backed view from a storyboard. You can do most of the layout in your storyboard, but then you will have to programmatically build your nib backed views and add them to the scroll view.

As a side note, it sounds like you are building something that could be solved with a UITableView and a prototype cell. Here is a [pretty good tutorial](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html).